# Java servlet redirect between two different jersey REST services

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, servlet-filters

We have an existing Jersey REST service in our application(URL: /rest/*). 
A sample URL looks like: `http://xxx:8080/app/rest/company/getdata`

Based on a **property** we need to redirect the REST call to another context(URL: /newrest/*):
A sample URL would look like: `http://xxx:8080/app/newrest/company/getdata`

So, I added a servlet mapping in my web.xml.

So, My web.xml looks like the below snippet.

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>xxx.httpservice</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  
<filter>
    <filter-name>secureRESTFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>xxx.RESTSecurityFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>secureRESTFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>NewAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>xxx.newhttpservice</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NewAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/newrest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have written a filter(to check for the **property** on the ServletAdaptor servlet and I need to redirect to the NewAdaptor servlet, if needed. Also, the final response should be sent back by the Servlet Adaptor servlet using the response from NewAdaptor servlet, if necessary(based on the property).

I need directions for solving this issue. Please help.

The dofilter method in my filter class looks like:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {     
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;    
    String productMode = "b";//hardcoded for this example    
    String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    if(productMode.equals("a")){
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }else{
        url=url.replace("rest", "newrest");
        req.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(req, res);
    }

}
```

But the RequestDispatcher does not seem to forward the request to the new url.

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand you are trying to create new services or integrate newer one.
Ideally you can version the URL's to support backward compatibilty in future.e.g.
http://{xxx}:8080/app/rest/v1_0/company/getdata,http://{xxx}:8080/app/rest/v2_0/company/getdata etc.

Why don't you wrap the new API call in the existing API call? So that the consumer talks to your API, internally you invoke the newer API and consume the response of it.Then you either return the new object or wrap your object around it.

You need to really re-look at the strategy you are trying to adopt!

Comment: The client can have only one URL such as http://xxx:8080/app/rest/company/getdata. The server needs to decide which one to call /rest/ or /newrest/. Its not exactly different versions, its more like two different data sources. Could you please explain the wrapping part more clearly? if possible with an example. Thanks!!

Comment: 2 REST Services (REST1,REST2). Communication should be REST Client->Server->REST API->Server Code.Internal code of the server should invoke the newer API based on the discriminator/property you have.Server code will act like a REST client which would call the newer API.  You can check out this blog as to how to create a REST client https://blogs.oracle.com/sandoz/entry/jersey_client_api